# How does the Seasons Clock work?

Tags: pokemon-black-white

In either **Pokemon White** or **Pokemon Black**, the seasons switch regularly. The problem is, We're in *Fall* and it's saying that the season is *Spring*. Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The season cycle is dependent on the calendar, so the seasons might off depending on where you live. Each season lasts a real-time month, thus the seasons cycle every *four* months.

- **Spring** - *January, May, September*
- **Summer** - *February, June, October*
- **Autumn** - *March, July, November*
- **Winter** - *April, August, December*

Therefore, if you want to be in a specific season, you'll want to change the month in your system clock.